# calculate vehicle trip

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I want to calculate the vehicle trip but facing problem. No Groupby is working .

```
select z.ZoneId, o.ObjectId,o.Number,o.Comment,z.Name StartTrip,zs.TimeFirst,zs.Inside,z.ZoneGroupId

from dbo.Object o join 
dbo.GroupObject gobj on o.ObjectId = gobj.ObjectId join 
dbo.[Group] g on gobj.GroupId=g.GroupId join 
dbo.[ZoneState] zs on o.ObjectId=zs.ObjectId join 
dbo.[Zone] z on zs.ZoneId=z.ZoneId
where (z.ZoneGroupId=1 OR z.ZoneGroupId=2) and o.ObjectId=3414 and (convert(date,zs.TimeFirst)>='2016/2/15') and (convert(date,zs.TimeFirst)<='2016/3/24')  

ORDER BY o.Number
```

Current Result

```
ZoneId  Objectid Number commants StartTrip TimeFirst          Inside 
 540    3414    VT-0678T VOLVO   Oil Fd  2016-03-17 17:10:31    0   
 543    3414    VT-0678T VOLVO   Khour   2016-03-19 09:38:30    1   
 540    3414    VT-0678T VOLVO   Oil Fd  2016-03-21 07:32:58    0    
 543    3414    VT-0678T VOLVO   Khour   2016-03-22 07:29:56    1  
 540    3414    VT-0678T VOLVO   Oil Fd  2016-03-22 15:22:41    0       
 543    3414    VT-0678T VOLVO   Khour   2016-03-24 07:41:27    1
```

Required Result

```
ObjId Number   StartTrip EndTrip  TimeFirst            TimeLast 
3414  VT-0678T Oil Fd    Khour   2016-03-17 17:10:31 2016-03-19 09:38:30
3414  VT-0678T Oil Fd    Khour   2016-03-21 07:32:58 2016-03-22 07:29:56
3414  VT-0678T Oil Fd    Khour   2016-03-22 15:22:41 2016-03-24 07:41:27
```

Comment: What is the problem?  Your attached image is very small and hard to read.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen please open image new tab. you clearly view the required result

Comment: a good way to ask is to create some sample data and provide expected result.Do you really think any one will be able to judge the output you want based on your screenshot ?

Comment: Looks like a just a group by query.

Comment: @TheGameiswar Question update.

Comment: @Used_By_Already can you give me a idea on which field i apply groupby.

Comment: You group by the coulmns that don't change between your data and the expected result. So all the columns before the dates columns of the reault. Then MIN and  MAX of the dates.  Im using just a phone so writing formatted code is almost impossible.

Comment: I don't think it is not a simple `GROUP BY`

Comment: @enigma, can you explain what is Inside ?

Comment: @Squirrel inside indicate vehicle enter and left the specific area.1 mean enter and 0 mean left the area.

Comment: @TheGameiswar still waiting for your answer

Comment: do you need one record for one date? also are you doing any arthematic operations. In desired result what is `cont` at the last... what exactly are you trying as I can see data was similar and only date and time are changing. group by in which column are you trying to use

Comment: @siva i want to calculate trip of vehicle.date,starttrip and inside status also change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  DataTable dtRequiredResult = GetRequiredResultTableDefinition();

    bool flag = true;

            DataRow rowtoAdd = dtRequiredResult.NewRow();

            for (int j = 0; j < dtQueryResult.Rows.Count; j++)
            {
                if (dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["Status"].ToString() == "0")
                {
                    if (flag)
                    {
                        rowtoAdd["Z From"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["Z.Id"].ToString();
                        rowtoAdd["Veh"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["Veh"].ToString();
                        rowtoAdd["Start"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["Zone"].ToString();
                        rowtoAdd["S Date"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["DateTime"].ToString();
                        flag = false;
                    }
                }
                if (dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["Status"].ToString() == "1")
                {
                    if (rowtoAdd["Start"].ToString() == dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["Zone"].ToString())
                    {
                        rowtoAdd["Z To"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j-1]["Z.Id"].ToString();
                        rowtoAdd["End"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j - 1]["Zone"].ToString();
                        rowtoAdd["E Date"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[j]["DateTime"].ToString();
                        dtRequiredResult.Rows.InsertAt(rowtoAdd, dtRequiredResult.Rows.Count);
                        rowtoAdd = dtRequiredResult.NewRow();
                        flag = true;
                    }
                }
            }

            rowtoAdd["Z To"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[dtQueryResult.Rows.Count-1]["Z.Id"].ToString();
            rowtoAdd["End"] = dtQueryResult.Rows[dtQueryResult.Rows.Count-1]["Zone"].ToString();
            dtRequiredResult.Rows.InsertAt(rowtoAdd, dtRequiredResult.Rows.Count);



 private DataTable GetRequiredResultTableDefinition()
    {
        DataTable table = new DataTable("Required");

        DataColumn col = new DataColumn("Z From", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn("Z To", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn("Veh", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn("Start", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn("End", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn("S Date", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        col = new DataColumn("E Date", typeof(string));
        col.AllowDBNull = true;
        table.Columns.Add(col);

        return table;
    }
```